# Syntax highlighting stopped working in Blazor Server project

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.8.1 and the project targets NET 5.0.

The whole code section is highlighted.  Is this normal?

[image: ~Everything is grey~]

Comment: Hrmm internal `Person` class and `Person` property is probably causing some sort of ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-opened the file/re-opened Visual Studio. @Brian Yes there was ambiguity but i think a broken build somewhere